# Simulating keyboard events with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testing, automation

How to simulate typing of some text in a contenteditable element?
I need to simulate everything as a user will events will do for test purposes.
I can fire an event with:

```
node.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: 'A'}))
node.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {key: 'A'}))
```

But it will not print `A`. So I have to use API:

```
node.innerHTML += 'A'
```

But the cursor will be in a different place, so I need to create a range.

```
let r = document.createRange()
r.selectNodeContents(editor)
r.collapse(false)
let s = window.getSelection()!
s.removeAllRanges()
s.addRange(r)
```

What about simulating arrows? How to simulate arrow up? Maybe there is some library to do this?

Answer (score -1):

[Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/) is a great option for simulating user interactions. It can be paired with a companion library, [user-event](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/), to simulate user input such as click, dblClick, arrow up/down, tab, and much more. Here's an example of simulating user input in a text field:

```js
import { screen } from '@testing-library/dom';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('type', () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = `<textarea />`;

  // type 'Hello' followed by the enter key, followed by 'World!' into the textarea
  userEvent.type(screen.getByRole('textbox'), 'Hello,{enter}World!');
  // We expect that textarea to now have the given value
  expect(screen.getByRole('textbox')).toHaveValue('Hello,\nWorld!');
});
```

You can delay the input, or use the `skipClick` option to input before clicking the element (in the case where the element auto-focuses, for example).

There are tons of examples here: https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/. They also have wrappers for various frameworks such as react, angular, and puppeteer. So depending on what framework you use (or just vanilla js), you can:

1. Create your page/component
2. Simulate user input events with the user-event library
3. Assert certain conditions that you expect to be true

I also really like that the library makes it easy to mock server requests so I can fully test a component without worrying about its internals and how it's structured.

Comment: Unfortunately not working on contenteditable https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/442